# Filtering For Specific Numbers Criteria in R DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have dataframe":

```
a <- data.frame(b_1=c(0.03,2.241,5.72,0.3566,1.344,2.5))
```

and I want to use filter like

```
a <- a %>% filter(b_1 %in% 0.)
```

so I exclude row that value not in 0,... in b_1.

But the code above was not working

The result is 0.03 and 0.3566

I have a big data, so it just an example dataframe that I want to filter. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%in%` is looking for fixed match and none of the elements will satisfy that criteria.  We can use substring match with `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
a %>%
   filter(str_detect(b_1, '^0\\.'))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(a, grepl("^0\\.", b_1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
a %>% filter(between(b_1, -1, 1))
     b_1
1 0.0300
2 0.3566
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `abs(b_1-0.5) < 0.5` as a condition to limit the interval to `(0,1)`

```
> subset(a, abs(b_1 - 0.5) < 0.5)
     b_1
1 0.0300
4 0.3566
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to keep values greater than or equal to 1.If yes, then you can filter those values and save them into a new df:

```
b<-dplyr::filter(a,b_1 >= 1)
b
    b_1
  2.241
  5.720
  1.344
  2.500
```

If you want to keep values less than one:

```
c<-dplyr::filter(a,b_1 < 1)
c
 b_1
 0.0300
 0.3566
```